# material ui lab autocomplete its not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete its not working for me, just don't allow me to select and option and the placeholder it's always ther even if a type,

here:
[image]

here it's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export default function FreeSolo() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Autocomplete
        id="free-solo-demo"
        freeSolo
        options={top100Films.map(option => option.title)}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} label="freeSolo"   onInputValueChange={event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, value: any} => void margin="normal" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
  { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 }
];
```

it is the same code og the documentation but it doesn't work.

maybe can be something with the version, here is part of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "....",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.3",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "date-and-time": "^0.10.0",
    "downshift": "^4.0.4",
    "firebase": "^7.2.2",
    "notistack": "^0.9.7",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-hooks": "^1.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You made at least two errors.

1. You should use latest for `@material-ui/lab` so it should be `"@material-ui/lab": "latest",` in package.json
2. You should not use map to get only titles of the movies in options
3. `onInputValueChange` does not exist in your code and there is no such props in API of MaterialUI. Also, you are returning void from that function which is undefined.

I created codesandbox with functioning component that you need and you can find it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vexgl